# Restore savedInstanceState before Fragments onCreate method

Tags: android, android-fragments, savestate

I made a test application so I can learn how to save the `InstanceState`.

Now we have a Main Fragment Activity and two Tab Fragments. I have a variable in the Main Activity that it's value sat in the `onCreate` method.. and I would like to share it with the fragments.

So I created a public method in the Main Activity to call it inside the fragments when I need the value of that variable. `((TMainActivity) getActivity()).getTestString()`

The problem is when the device is rotated I got the default value of the string and not the saved value.

And that's obviously because `onRestoreInstanceState` is called after the `onCreate` of the fragments.

Now, how can I work that out?

**TMainActivity.java**

```
public class TMainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    final private static String TAG = "TMainActivity";
    final private static String EXTRA_TEST = "MAIN_KEY";

    private CollectionPagerAdapter mCollectionPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mainPager;

    private String test = "Default";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate() Before test= " + test);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            test = "New";
        } else {
            test = savedInstanceState.getString(EXTRA_TEST) + " - Restored";
        }

        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate() After test= " + test);

        mainPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_pager);

        mCollectionPagerAdapter = new CollectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mainPager.setAdapter(mCollectionPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        Log.v(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState()");

        outState.putString(EXTRA_TEST, test);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        Log.v(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState()");
        Log.v(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState() savedInstanceState=" + (savedInstanceState != null));

        test = savedInstanceState.getString(EXTRA_TEST);
    }

    public String getTestString() {
        return test;
    }

    private class CollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public CollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Tab1Fragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Tab2Fragment();
                break;
            }

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
        }
    }

}
```

**Tab1Fragment.java**

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

    final private static String TAG = "Tab1Fragment";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate()");
        Log.v(TAG, "getTestString()=" + ((TMainActivity) getActivity()).getTestString());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_tab1, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

**Tab2Fragment.java**

```
public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {

    final private static String TAG = "Tab2Fragment";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate()");
        Log.v(TAG, "getTestString()=" + ((TMainActivity) getActivity()).getTestString());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_tab2, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. First is called `onCreate` in the Activity and in this method you have already available that Bundle with your data. That means that you can restore the Activity and then use the data in `onCreateView` of the Fragment which is called later.

Basically you do not override the `onRestoreInstanceState()` method, but rename it and call it from `onCreate` in your Activity. The reason not to override that method is because it would be called 2 times—from `onCreate` by you and then as a part of the Activity life-cycle. That would reset the value if it was changed in the Fragment.

In your case you can just move

```
Log.v(TAG, "getTestString()=" + ((TMainActivity) getActivity()).getTestString());
```

from `onCreate` to `onCreateView`.

This not a good solution when you're restoring large amount of data. Your UI thread would get stuck on restoring the Activity. But in such a case you can restore just some part of the data that is needed in the Fragment and the rest restore in `onRestoreInstanceState`.